# iterate through dataframe and execute code base on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a DataFrame as below, I would like to create a new column "Six" such that this column's value is dependent on the value of "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth" column value.

Column 0 is a string (Sentence that has grammatical error, I'm doing NLP project)

Column 1 to Column 5 is actually the position of the error and whats the correction. I will have a code to correct the sentence in Column 0

if value = NaN, it means there is no more error after the first 2 error.

How do I loop through each row and column to get the final out put for Column 6

Understand that a loop needs to be created...need help to get this started. Thanks

```
Actual Input

A   0   1   2   3   4   5
S                                                       
8   If your genetic...  10 10|||the|||  26 26|||will||| NaN NaN NaN 
9   However for...      11 11|||,|||    9 10|||specific NaN NaN NaN


Expected output

A   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
S                                                       
8   If your genetic...  10 10|||the|||  26 26|||will||| NaN NaN NaN  'Sentence with no error'
9   However for...      11 11|||,|||    9 10|||specific NaN NaN NaN  'Sentence with no error'
```

Comment: Does this look like you are counting a number of 1's in every column and store the result in Six columns?

Comment: Hi not really, let me edit my data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a loop like:

First ensure the index does not contain duplicates:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then loop through the rows and loop through the columns and finally place the answer in column 6:

```
for idx in df.index:
    for i range(6):    # loop through the columns and do what you need to do here
        colVal = df.loc[idx,i]  #contains value of the column i
        # do whatever
    df.loc[idx,6] = your_answer   # assign the value to column 6
```